# Image crop/resize returns more of the image then selected. PHP

Tags: php

I'm creating a image resizing tool. The selecting etc is done with JavaScript and then the values is sent to PHP. That is working perfectly fine. But, The image is not correctly resized. The new images get the correct width/height but, the selected part of the image get's "zoomed" and more of the image compared to what's selected is returned. An example on the images below.

Image width/height before resizing

Width: 280px 
Height: 210px

Resize Details

[image: Resize details]

Output image

[image: Output image]

```
<?php

    $width = 163.094;
    $height = 148.5;
    $new_width = 62.18745;
    $new_height = 69.87505;

    $dst_left = 0;
    $dst_top = 0;
    $src_left = 49.15625;
    $src_top = 39.03125;

    header('Content-Type: image/png');

    // Create a empty image
    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

    // Set background transparent
    imagefill($new_image,0,0,0x7fff0000);

    // Create image
    $image = imagecreatefrompng("../../uploads/img/imageNX4jDQ.png");

    // Create new image
    imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image, $dst_left, $dst_top, $src_left, $src_top, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

    // Keep transparency
    imageAlphaBlending($new_image, true);
    imageSaveAlpha($new_image, true);

    // Output
    $test = imagepng($new_image, "../../uploads/img/test.png");

    $test;

?>
```

Comment: Have a look at your arguments for imagecopyresampled()

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with them? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This diagram always helps me:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php#112742

That aside I would anticipate your JS passing through an original width of 62.18745, and height of 69.87505.

If you need to scale the image down after that then your new_width and height values will have to be adjusted in accordance to what you need them to be.

Comment: I had misunderstood the imagecopyresampled() function. I realized I had to resize the image first with the orginal size. Then copy the part i want and generate a new image from that.

Comment: This diagram always helps me:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php#112742

Comment: oh look, I answered in a comment first and got no points. WHY BOTHER?